# R - Plotting a time series with NA results with ggplot2

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2, time-series

I have a data set that contains power data taken every 20th of a second.  The problem seems to lie with variable `Moment.1` and `Active_Power` which  contain `NA` values. The resulted plot of variable `Moment` appears fine. Below is my code and here is a screenshot of My data:

[image: My Data]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(reshape2)

Flatcsv <-"../FlatRock/data.csv"
FlatData <- read.csv(Flatcsv,sep = ",",na.strings = "NULL")
ggplot(FlatData, aes(x=strptime(Timestamp_EST,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"), ymax=50000)) + 
   geom_line(aes(y=Moment),col="blue") +  
   geom_line(aes(y=Active_Power), col="red") +  
   scale_x_datetime(name="Date/Time", breaks = date_breaks("1 min"), 
       labels = date_format(format = "%H:%M:%S \n %Y/%m/%d"), 
       minor_breaks = date_breaks("20 sec")) +
   scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,50000),name="Moment (kN*m)")
```

The only visible line is the plot of variable.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This may not solve your problem, but I suggest using the `complete.cases` function to remove the NA cases in the data frame in order to simplify and to speed up the call to ggplot.

Comment: Is it the case that `FlatData$Active_Power` only contains one non-NA observation?